# Pasar el Value de un Input como parametro a una función desde un evento DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Buenas estoy haciendo una calculadora común mediante botones en JS, tengo este html:

```
 <li>
            <input id="uno" type="button" value="1" class="numero" >
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="dos" type="button" value="2" class="numero" >
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="tres" type="button" value="3" class="numero" >
        </li>
```

Y en el script tengo esto:

```
   document.getElementsByClassName('numero').onclick = añadirCuenta(numero.value)



    function añadirCuenta(valor) {
        cuentaTexto += valor
        document.getElementById('mostrador-cuenta').innerHTML = cuentaTexto;
    }
```

La función no es el problema si mando el argumento desde el html y onclick. Pero no sé, o no consigo entender como se hace llamando el evento desde el script, llamando a la clase, y que se cargue el "value" como parámetro para llamar la función.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría así:

```js
lista = document.getElementById('lista');

lista.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("numero")) {
    añadirCuenta(event.target.value)
  }
})

var cuentaTexto = ''

function añadirCuenta(valor) {
  cuentaTexto += valor
  document.getElementById('mostrador-cuenta').innerHTML = cuentaTexto;
}
```

```html
<div id="lista">
  <li>
    <input id="uno" type="button" value="1" class="numero">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="dos" type="button" value="2" class="numero">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="tres" type="button" value="3" class="numero">
  </li>
</div>
<div id="mostrador-cuenta"></div>
```

Donde encerramos todos los campos *input* en un solo *div*, al cual le ponemos el *id* `lista`, que ponemos a la escucha del evento `click` mediante el método `addEventListener()`, y si el botón pulsado tiene la clase `numero` entonces lanzamos la función `añadirCuenta` con el valor de dicho *input*, el cual identificamos con `event.target.value` donde `event.target` identifica al elemento pulsando en el evento, y `value` es su atributo.

Luego, dentro de la función, en la variable `cuentaTexto` le concatenamos el valor del botón pulsado.

Para luego, finalmente, mostrarlo en el *div* con *id* `mostrador-cuenta` con el `innerHTML`.

Comment: Creo que quiere concatenar los números, no sumarlos: pulsando 1,2 y 3 debería mostrar '123', como en una calculadora. Por lo demás, me parece una buena solución

Comment: @PabloLozano ah, vaya, mmm... seguramente tienes razon... voy a quitar los parseInt entonces, gracias!

Comment: @PabloLozano llevaba razón, quité el parse cuando me dí cuenta, gracias a los dos!